# Why does the border on this `<li>` tag vanish?

Tags: html, css

I am recreating the [Kotaku website](https://www.kotaku.com) and am having trouble creating a list in the footer. Below is an image describing what I mean.

The 'Popular tags' section has been created with a `<ul>` `<li>` with an `<a>` inside the list item. This `<li>` has a right-border of 1px to create a divider but on the end item (circled in red) this divider is not there, but from my limited understanding it should be. This happens with whatever item is last on the line before being turned over to another line, so resizing the window the end item never has a border. I cannot recreate this.

I am unsure how to display the code relevant to this as the CSS displayed in Devtools for just the `<a>` tag is 103 lines long and I am unsure what use this would be. What I can say is removing the 'display:inline-block' from the `<a>` tag inside the list item makes the border return and I cannot think why this is.

Could anyone take a look at the Kotaku page and explain to me how this is done? I appreciate I am asking a lot but I can think of no other way to properly explain it than checking it out as I cannot even find a resource online explaining this behaviour, this is my last attempt before I just fudge it for now.

Thanks.

[Kotaku website footer, red circle highlights missing border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vPrU.jpg)

[image]

This question has been rewritten to make it more legible

Comment: it probably just has text-decoration set to none

Comment: I'd look for a :last CSS pseudo-selector; there are a couple of different types

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

So I made an isolated example of this and managed to get the desired result. I couldn't for the life of me understand why it worked, and didn't get much useful help online I am gonna chalk that up to my poor description.

I've done some tests and it turns out that the issue is due to whitespace in the html. So I originally wrote my code like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
```

This resulted in the last items on a line having a border applied to them which makes complete sense to me and is how I expected it to work. But it was not what was on the Kotaku website and I was not using any styles different to them.

It turns out that I should have written my code like this:

```
<li>
 <a href="#">Item</a>
</li>
```

I don't really get whitespace at the moment but it is the whitespace that is causing me the heartache. Sorted now.

Here is the code that works for me.

```css
#container {
  max-width: 970px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

#ul {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 80%;
}

.list-item {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.list-item:last-child {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.link {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul id="ul">
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 6</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 7</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 8</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 9</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 10</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 11</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 12</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 13</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 14</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 15</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 16</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 17</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 18</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 19</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 20</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 21</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">
      <a href="#" class="link">Item 22</a>
    </li>


  </ul>


</div>
```